# Dynamodb - Get all rows with a hash key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to get all rows from DynamoDB that use a specific hash key when your rows use both hash key and range key?

Example:

`Hash           Range 
A              B
A              C
A              D
E              F`

Then getItems(Hash=A) returns 3 rows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using the **Query API**. Here is the sample code (Node JS).

I have a `Movie` table with hash key (year key) and sort key (title). I have queried using the hash key. I have got four items in the result i.e. four titles available for the year 1992.

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();    
var table = "Movies";    
var year_val = 1992;    
var params = {
    TableName : table,
    KeyConditionExpression : 'yearkey = :hkey',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ':hkey' : year_val      
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to read item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err,
                null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("GetItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```